# How to set breakpoint at NSObject class method alloc, I want to see the call tree

Tags: ios, xcode

just as the title asks, I want to see what happened when call the NSObject class method alloc, wonder to know what the method call then.

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to subclass the NSObject and you need to alloc like this

```
Apple *someObject = [[Apple alloc] init];
```

Now apple is a subclass of NSObject. By default, you don't have init method. So you need to write inside the apple.m file and put breakpoint inside `-(void)init{}`.

Actually, when this code executes the `-(void)init{}` method will get called inside the .m file.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I'm afraid you don't get my point , I want to know how what the 'alloc' method call after itself executed. For instance, it will call '+allocWithZone:',then 'class_createInstance',and then 'calloc'. I get this by reading a book, but don't know how to set breakpoint to get this.